# Is there a way to disable or analyze Serilog parameter rendering of Task<T>?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I've recently refactored a method that retrieves a username from a dictionary of connected users to be asynchronous:

```
public static string GetUsername(this Guid id) => ...
public static async Task<string> GetUsernameAsync(this Guid id) => await ...
```

I expected a large refactor with Serilog usage, as I have hundreds of places that use this logging like so:

```
Log.Debug("User {UserName} disconnected from {IP}, saving", guid.GetUsername(), IP);
```

I renamed the method GetUsername to GetUsernameAsync, expecting hundreds of warnings that I could simply go through and refactor to "awaits" (both the serilog calls and the containing methods), but no such warnings appeared. I was expecting it to Warn, so that I could refactor the calls to something like:

```
Log.Debug("User {UserName} disconnected from {IP}, saving", await guid.GetUsernameAsync(), IP);
```

But alas, Serilog dutifully renders those "strings" as "Task strings" and grants me messages (synchronously) like so:

```
[08:57:09 DBG] System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] disconnected from 127.0.0.1:64022, saving
```

Is there a way to do this refactor easily? Some configuration setting of Serilog or Analyzer that warns on Task parameters?

Comment: No, because what you want to do in each case is not easily automated. You most likely do *not* want each log statement to embed an `await` in there, instead you might want to move the log statement down below where you have actually awaited the task to obtain its results. If you really want to embed an `await` inside each such log statement, you will have to just go around adding it in each case. Be prepared for the surrounding method to become async as well though.

Comment: I am intending to actually await on this particular logging, since the Guid cannot really be retrieved with the database offline, and I have a caching mechanism for the usernames. In other words - if the logging calls are problematic because of the await, I have more serious issues in play (which I have hopefully logged/handled more gracefully). I'm definitely prepared for the async refactor, though. It would just be nice to know *what* to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas:

1. If you want to add `await` for all (or even most) instances of the refactored method, you could use global find and replace in the IDE.

   1. For Visual Studio you can access this via the menu `Edit > Find and Replace > Replace in Files` (default keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+H`) and use these settings:

      - Search string: `(?:await\s+)?\b(\w+\.GetUsernameAsync)`
      - Replace string: `await $1`
      - NOTE: The regex matches (but doesn't capture) an optional leading `await` so that if you've partially done the refactor by updating some usages you won't end up with `await await` in those places. It uses a word boundary (`\b`) and word characters (`\w`) so that it works with any variable name wherever `GetUsernameAsync` may be called.
   2. You should now have compiler errors for usages of `await` from non-`async` methods, which you can go through and fix manually.
   3. If needed, you can manually remove the `await` for specific usages of `GetUsernameAsync` where you don't want to immediately await the method (I'm guessing this is likely a rare or non-existent case).
2. To review the results of your refactor or just use a more 1-by-1 manual approach instead of global find and replace, you can use Visual Studio `Find All References` (right click context menu for the method) and then enter `log` in the "Search Find All References" textbox in upper right of the tool window to focus on logging-related usages.
3. You could look at [implementing your own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022) Roslyn [code analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2022) based on existing examples. While this may not be trivial (weigh the development and testing effort vs. the time to do a very large number of manual updates to `await` the refactored method) or be the easiest option for the refactor, it covers the "is there an analyzer?" part of your question. The [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading) project includes a number of [analyzers](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/index.md) and is open source. Particularly the analyzer with ID [VSTHRD110](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD110.md) ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers.CSharp/VSTHRD110ObserveResultOfAsyncCallsAnalyzer.cs)), which recommends observing the result of async calls (from non-async methods), may be a useful starting point. Out of the box, I don't think this analyzer would issue a warning for your specific use case because the return value from your async version of `GetUsernameAsync` is passed as an argument to a `Log` method. Hence the result is not entirely unused. However, you may be able to adjust it to create a new analyzer for your use case.

Comment: Thanks - this is pretty close to what I'll do - the volume of logging messages containing this extension method is quite... voluminous, so it's a fair bit of work which I'm hoping is comprehensive. Using a regex on the search hadn't occurred to me, though. Great idea!

Comment: @Chris I'm glad you found the search with regex option helpful. For the sake of completeness, I updated my answer to include a third option of writing your own analyzer, referencing an example so that the task may be easier than starting from scratch. However, the search / replace with regex option may still be a quicker option.